# CSS: trouble with background url in linux

Tags: html, css, background

For the creation of a (local) website, I have wrote and tested some html and css files on Windows 7. Now I am trying to export these files on Linux (Debian) where I have installed apache2...

In one of my css file, I have the following lines :

```
html {
     ...
     background: url(../Images/texture.png);
     ...
}
```

The problem is that it does not work on Linux, texture.png is not found.

I have the same folders tree on each OS, which is :

```
site/
    html/        /* css file is here */
    Images/      /* texture.png is here */
```

On Debian, I have tried to put texture.png in the html folder :

```
site/
     html/   /* css file and texture.png are here */
```

and modifying the css file like this :

```
html {
     ...
     background: url(texture.png);
     ...
}
```

And it works fine.

I don't really understand why the first path does not work, is there a thing that i have missed ?

Thank you ;)

Comment: Have you tried `background: url('../Images/texture.png');`?

Comment: Is the *site* directory your webroot or is the *html* directory?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `background : url("../Images/texture.png")` and `background : url('../Images/texture.png')`, but It still does not work...

Comment: Where is the file that is loading the CSS file located? Or is the CSS in the head?

Comment: There is `index.html` in `site/html/` which load the file `style.css` in the same folder

Comment: You still haven't answered my question.  Which directory is your webroot directory?  Is it html or is it site?  If it is site, and Images (or images, whichever you've renamed it to) is not web accessible (because it is not located within the webroot), then everything within that directory will return a 404.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this comment. The webroot directory is `html`. So If I understand what you said I have to all the files under my webroot directory ?

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Indeed, I have set the `html` directory as webroot, as the `Images` directory was not in the webroot, the texture.png was not accessible. Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that needs to be web accessible is *usually* placed within the webroot directory (there are ways to do this without physically moving the items, but this is not my area of expertise).

If the `html` directory is your webroot, then `Images` is not accessible from the web

```
site/
    html/        /* webroot */
    Images/      /* not accessible from the web :-( */
```

The simplest solution would be to move the `Images` directory to live inside `html`, though you could also set `site` to be your webroot directory instead if that makes more sense for your project.

```
site/
    html/        /* webroot */
        Images/  /* accessible from the web :-) */
```